# Time-reversal transformation acts on the Weyl lagrangian with nonabelian gauge field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, time-reversal-symmetry, cpt-symmetry

I would like to show time-reversal transformation acts on the Weyl lagrangian in the familiar 4 dimensional space-time.

My notation follows the same as Peskin QFT book, such as that of chapter 3. I use the Lorentz signature $(+,-,-,-)$. We shall treat the fermion $\psi$ as Grassmann variable which anticommutes with another Grassmann variable. It may be helpful to think the Weyl lagrangian
$\psi^\dagger_L (i \bar \sigma^\mu (\partial_\mu - i g A_\mu) )\psi_L$ occurs as the exponent that we do the path integral formulation.

$T$ is antiunitary so we have:
$Ti T^{-1} = -i$.

$T$ on Dirac fermion is

$T: T\psi(t,x) T^{-1}=  -\gamma^1  \gamma^3 \psi(-t,x)$.

$T$ on Weyl fermion:

$T\psi_L(t,x)T^{-1}
=- i \sigma^2\psi_L(-t,x)$

$T\psi_R(t,x)T^{-1}
=- i \sigma^2\psi_R(-t,x)$.

$T$ on a generic non-Abelian $A$ gauge boson (see **p.s.1. at the end below**):

$TA_\mu(t,x)T^{-1}= A'_\mu(-t,x)$ where we define the right-and side $A'_\mu(-t,x)$ as

$TA_0(t,x)T^{-1}= -A_0(-t,x)$
and $TA_j(t,x)T^{-1}= A_j(-t,x)$ with $j=1,2,3$.

We denote $A_\mu=(A_0,A_j)$ and $A_\mu'=(-A_0,A_j)$ with $j=1,2,3$.

In general $A_\mu(t,x)= A_\mu^\alpha(t,x) X^\alpha$ where $X$ is a hermitian Lie algebra generator.

$T X T^{-1}= X$.

Check the $T$ symmetry acts on the Weyl lagrangian

$\psi^\dagger_L (i \bar \sigma^\mu (\partial_\mu - i g A_\mu) )\psi_L$

here we use the standard notation for Pauli matrix

$\sigma^\mu=(\sigma^0,\sigma^1,\sigma^2,\sigma^3)$

and $\bar \sigma^\mu=(\sigma^0,-\sigma^1,-\sigma^2,-\sigma^3)$.

Then, $T  \bar \sigma^\mu  T^{-1}=\bar \sigma^{\mu *}$.

Also I believe that $T (\partial_\mu  \psi_L(t,x)) T^{-1}=\partial_\mu (T  \psi_L(t,x) T^{-1})=
\partial_\mu (- i \sigma^2\psi_L(-t,x))$. Below we denote $\partial_{\mu'} \equiv (-\partial_{0},\partial_{j})=(\partial_{-t},\partial_{j})$ in contrast to $\partial_{\mu}=(\partial_{0},\partial_{j})$.

$$
T \psi^\dagger_L (i \bar \sigma^\mu (\partial_\mu - i g A_\mu) )\psi_L T^{-1}
= T \psi^\dagger_L  T^{-1} T i T^{-1} T  \bar \sigma^\mu  T^{-1} T (\partial_\mu - i g A_\mu) \psi_L T^{-1}
$$

$$
= (- i \sigma^2 \psi_L)^\dagger  (- i ) (  \bar \sigma^{\mu *} ) T (\partial_\mu - i g A_\mu) \psi_L T^{-1}
$$

$$
=  \psi_L^\dagger (+ i \sigma^2) (- i ) (  \bar \sigma^{\mu *} )  (\partial_\mu -(- i) g A'_\mu) (- i \sigma^2 \psi_L)
$$

$$
=  \psi_L^\dagger  (- i ) (   \sigma^{\mu } )  (\partial_\mu -(- i) g A'_\mu) ( \psi_L(-t,x))
$$

$$
=  \psi_L^\dagger  (- i ) (   \sigma^{\mu }  \partial_\mu -(- i) g   \sigma^{\mu }A'_\mu  ) ( \psi_L(-t,x))
$$

$$
=  \psi_L^\dagger  (- i ) (  - \bar \sigma^{\mu }  \partial_{\mu'} -(- i) g (-  \bar \sigma^{\mu }A_\mu)  ) ( \psi_L(-t,x))
$$

$$
=  \psi_L^\dagger  ( i    \bar  \sigma^{\mu }  (\partial_{\mu'} + i g  A_\mu) )  \psi_L(-t,x) \tag{1}
$$

with the last line all space-time coordinates are in the $(-t,x)$ instead of $(t,x)$.

We use  $\sigma^2 \bar \sigma^{\mu *} \sigma^2=\sigma^2 (\sigma^0,-\sigma^1,\sigma^2,-\sigma^3)\sigma^2  
= (\sigma^0,\sigma^1,\sigma^2,\sigma^3) =\sigma^{\mu}$.

Also $\sigma^{\mu }( \partial_\mu  \psi_L(-t,x))
 =  (\sigma^{0}  \partial_t + \sum_j \sigma^{j} \partial_j ) \psi_L(-t,x) 
=(-\sigma^{0}  \partial_{-t} + \sum_j \sigma^{j} \partial_j ) \psi_L(-t,x)= - \bar\sigma^{\mu } \partial_{\mu'}  \psi_L(-t,x)$.

We also use that $\sigma^{\mu } A'_\mu = - \sigma^{0} A_0 +\sum_j \sigma^{j} A_j= -\bar\sigma^{\mu } A_\mu$.

(Did I miss something? Perhaps $T (\partial_\mu - i g A_\mu) \psi_L T^{-1}$ is a tricky part, but I think I did it perfectly.)

We conclude that

$$
T \psi^\dagger_L (i \bar \sigma^\mu (\partial_\mu - i g A_\mu) )\psi_L (t,x) T^{-1}
=  \psi_L^\dagger  ( i    \bar \sigma^{\mu }  (\partial_{\mu'} + i g  A_\mu) )  \psi_L(-t,x). \tag{1}
$$

This seems weird --- I show that the Weyl lagrangian is almost invariant under $T$ symmetry transformation,

except that the gauge field flipped sign in the lagrangian ($A_\mu$ becomes $-A_\mu(-t,x)$). But we can also derive on the

$$
T \psi^\dagger_R (i  \sigma^\mu (\partial_\mu - i g A_\mu) )\psi_R (t,x) T^{-1}
=  \psi_R^\dagger  ( i     \sigma^{\mu }  (\partial_{\mu'} + i g  A_\mu) )  \psi_R(-t,x). \tag{2}
$$

Then the two combined $\psi_L +\psi_R=\psi$ as DIrac fermion cannot be consistent with the fact that
the Dirac lagrangian is invariant under $T$.

### So my eq (1) and (2) disagree with Peskin QFT chap 3 statement in p.71. Somehow I shall get an extra minus sign on the gauge field - how to fix that?

---

### p.s.1.

One may wonder why we define
$TA_0(t,x)T^{-1}= -A_0(-t,x)$
and $TA_j(t,x)T^{-1}= A_j(-t,x)$ with $j=1,2,3$,
instead of $TA_0(t,x)T^{-1}= +A_0(-t,x)$
and $TA_j(t,x)T^{-1}= - A_j(-t,x)$, since this overall minus sign can fix the problem in my equation (1) and (2).

However, $TA_0(t,x)T^{-1}= -A_0(-t,x)$
and $TA_j(t,x)T^{-1}= A_j(-t,x)$ because this is true for generic nonabelian gauge field, after all
we have to send
$T F_{0 j}(t,x)T^{-1} = -F_{0 j}(-t,x)$
and $T F_{ j k}(t,x)T^{-1} = +F_{ j k}(-t,x)$
with $j,k=1,2,3$. This is true only if we define what we define
$TA_0(t,x)T^{-1}= -A_0(-t,x)$
and $TA_j(t,x)T^{-1}= A_j(-t,x)$, not the other way.

(Note that $TA_0(t,x)T^{-1}= +A_0(-t,x)$
and $TA_j(t,x)T^{-1}= - A_j(-t,x)$ make sense for Abelian gauge field only when we apply $T$ and charge conjugation $C$ together.)